# Xcode struct help

Tags: xcode, data-structures

So I am new to programming and even newer to Xcode. I am having trouble using a struct in Xcode. I have gotten to the point where I copied and pasted the code,

```
struct product {
    int weight;
    float price;
} ;

product apple;
```

from the c++ site, but when I try to declare the apple's weight via `apple.weight = 5;`
I get errors saying unknown type name 'apple' and expected unqualified Id at .

Comment: There is nothing wrong in what you do now as a C++ program. Posting the entire code could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: You have a structure, not a `typedef` structure.

You can use it as follows:

```
struct product {
  int weight;
  float price;
};

struct product apple;

void func() {
  apple.weight = 12;
}
```

However, if you use a typedef, you can give your datatype an actual name:

```
typedef struct { .. } product;

product apple;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
product apple;
apple.weight = 5;
```

This is valid code inside a function, but not at file scope.

Although at file scope you can initialize it like this:

```
product apple = { 5 };
```